# A synonym of 'failure' in the context of failing a challenge. (one word)

Tags: single-word-requests

Positively I'm using **completed** or **success** (I don't want to use successful) together with the word challenge.

Now I'm looking for the negative equivalent. However I can't use **unsuccess** because that doesn't exist. (And not **unsuccessful** either because I don't want to use **successful**)

I don't want to use **incomplete** either because that implies the challenge is still open for completion and I don't want to imply that.

I don't want to use **failure** either because some people could read that as "(you are a) failure".

Comment: I cannot think of anything except fail.

Comment: Could you give us some context? What are you describing with these words? How can _completed_ be equivalent to _success_? Why not use _successful_?

Comment: you could use "hit" and "missed"?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a euphemism like "differently successful"...let'em get over it, if they failed.

Comment: Perhaps unfulfilled, unsatisfied, left hanging, left on the table

Comment: @terdon : Hey Terdon, good seeing you again in another SO realm! : ) 
You can *rise to a challenge* but I'm not sure if a challenge can be *succesful*. However I'm sure an *attempt* can be *succesful*. I want to use the word I seek together with the word challenge though.

Comment: @mplungjan: *fail* is a tense of the verb *to fail*. So just writing *fail* wouldn't make sense (if used as a noun it would be failure I believe). *(you) failed* - *(you) succeeded* would make sense but I want to address the attempt(or rather the challenge), not the person who made the attempt.

Comment: @Bentley4 hi yourself :). If this is to be used in the context of a challenge, please [edit] your post to make that clear. A _challenge_ for example, can be _met_ or _risen to_ or not, as the case may be. The word will depend on the context in which you want to use it. Are you looking for titles? Column headers? Field names? Simple prose? Is there a tense you will be using it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed using this word to describe *challenges* and are looking for the opposite of *successful challenges*, I would go for *failed challenges*.

The verb *fail* does not necessarily refer to the person who made the attempt, it can just as well refer to the attempt itself:

> Police slam man's failed attempt to bike across Cook Strait [[1]](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11160891)
>
> Valley Police Beat: 10 arrested after failed attempt to drive across border [[2]](http://www.ivpressonline.com/news/local/valley-police-beat-arrested-after-failed-attempt-to-drive-across/article_31457d56-58b4-11e3-a7a5-001a4bcf6878.html)

However, you should bear in mind that a *successful challenge* is not one that you successfully met, it is one that successfully challenged you. If I were to be pedantic here I would understand it in fact as a challenge that you failed since the challenge itself was successful. Personally, I would change both instances to:

> Challenges met
>
> Challenges failed

Or,to make it even clearer that you are not slighting the person (unnecessary in my opinion, but your call):

> Met challenges
>
> Failed challenges

Comment: I'm gonna go with *challenge met* and *challenge failed*. Seems the best option so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's not one word, but 'fall short' comes to mind. It implies that you faced a challenge and tried to meet it, but did not succeed.

> In his fifth attempt, Jack challenged himself to break his previous endurance record. He *fell short* by only two hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could try ***expired***.

> The challenge expired before it could be successfully completed.

Answer (score 1):

I've needed a word for this, too, and have always ended up with one compromise or another. I find that one dictionary may confer legitimacy to an unconventional affix that others do not. The following are listed in roughly descending order of my personal preference at this moment.

- forfeiture, forfeit
- scratching *(as in billiards)*
- blanking *(as in drawing a blank, blanking out, or doing nothing)*
- zilching *(or a derivative of another informal vernacular for zero)*
- unachievement, nonachievement, underachievement
- unaccomplishment, nonaccomplishment
- unfulfillment, nonfulfillment
- miss, missing
- fault, default
- reneging, renege *(the meaning shifts with renegation)*
- abandonment
- loss, defeat, despair
- fouling *(as in a foul ball)*
- scrapping, scraping, scrubbing
- disappointment
- abortion, termination, nullification, annulment
- unmet, ineffective, ineffectual, feckless, fruitless, bootless, futile

Answer (score 0):

My first few choices are - *the defeated*, *the vanquished*.

As for a one word noun - *a loser*, *a nonperformer*, and *an underachiever*.

A few more compound words (they have their own entries in dictionaries) are - *a lost cause*, and *a lame duck*.

Comment: But that points to the person who took on the challenge, I want the word to point to the attempt of succeeding in the challenge.

Comment: Do you mean he quit before even trying?

Comment: No. Simply that an attempt was made to succeed but the person was not able to do it in the allotted time.

Comment: I think *nonperformer* and *underachiever* are quite close to your criteria.

Comment: That again points to the person rather then the attempt.

Comment: Perhaps *an unfulfilled challenge* or *an unfulfilling challenge* (depending on your viewpoint), then?

Comment: @Bentley4 "Effort"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word but **(challenge is) met** - **(challenge is) not met** seems to be the best option I can come up with so far. But it's probably less clear for a non-native speaker to understand then something like unsuccessful (while not being correct).